# Power consumption monitoring problem

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, power-management, powertop

I used powertop v.2.1 under Ubuntu 12.04 but it missed the power est. column.It's the same situation as described https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=796068‎ and that bug is supposed to be fixed already. 
I tried lm_sensors but it didn't give any voltage reading. [Here](http://pastebin.com/eP1pmvDX)'s a log for sensors-detect and sesnors. 
I am uncertain what caused the problem. I am running linux kernel 3.2.0-23-generic, ubuntu 12.04 distro on Lenovo thinkpad machine.
Are there any other linux utilty to monitor power consumption for different devices?

Comment: I see you've asked [your question over on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291904/missed-power-est-column-in-powertop) as well. Cross posting the same question on the various Stack Exchange sites is discouraged. In any event, someone over there suggested getting the latest PowerTOP (v2.3) to see if the bug was fixed. Did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

### Alternative Power Apps

There are several [power management apps listed on the Linux App finder site](http://linuxappfinder.com/system/powermanagement).

[image: ss of power apps]

Of the ones listed I've used GKrellM & PowerTOP. Perhaps one of these will suit your needs.

I did a quick look through most of these apps. I didn't see the feature where power consumption was broken down by device. I believe that feature is unique to PowerTOP! Feel free to look through the list of apps though. Perhaps I missed something.

### Compiling latest PowerTOP (v2.3)

There is a [newer version of PowerTOP available](https://01.org/powertop/downloads) from the Intel Open Source site.

I'd try downloading that and see if the bug referenced in your question, has been resolved. Looking through the [bugzilla ticket it would appear to be the case](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=796068#c4).

#### Issues with power consumption calculation in PowerTOP

This particular calculation requires that the current be measured over a period of time. Given this it doesn't show up with any meaningful values for a period of time.

*excerpt (from [wiki answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_calculate_the_power_consumption))*

> To calculate the power consumption of an electrical or electronic
>   device you have to multiply the voltage applied to the device times
>   the current consumed. This is a little trickier than it would first
>   appear; the voltage applied is usually 120 volts(117 to 125 but who's
>   counting?) the current consumed is a bit more complicated. To measure
>   this requires an ammeter ( an AC ammeter) and a little time. The
>   current consumption will not be constant, so it must be averaged over
>   time. The longer your time measurement the more accurate your power
>   measurement will be.

Comment: I finally get the power est. in powertop, someone suggest me to wait for hours before the power est will show. However, this is not written in their doc.

Comment: I agree, but I think it needs to build up a pool of measurements before it can perform that calculation. I've added some details to my answer that explain why this is the case.