# System energy consumption monitoring

Tags: monitoring, power-management

Do you know any apps that monitor system power consumption? Not just cpu, but all components, preferably?

---

**UPDATE - `powertop` & `powerstat`**

I found `powertop`, but it doesn't say much.

[image]

I've also found this question: [Power consumption monitoring problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74942/power-consumption-monitoring-problem) and its duplicate on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/291904/missed-power-est-column-in-powertop.

The answer is `powertop` needs a few hours to collect data before it provides calculations of power consumption. (Also *grochmal* advises this in his comments.) But this may not be the whole truth, in the light of what I found running `powertop` in the background.

```
$ sudo powertop &
[1] 20744
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~$ Loaded 0 prior measurements
Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only 
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL device for cpu 0
Devfreq not enabled
Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only
```

---

The Ask Ubuntu answer also mentions:

**`powerstat`**

It demands the laptop to run on battery (so not for RaspberryPi and desktops) and after 3 minutes gives this:

```
  Time    User  Nice   Sys  Idle    IO  Run Ctxt/s  IRQ/s Fork Exec Exit  Watts
03:28:26  20.2   0.0   2.4  77.4   0.1    1   1356    675    2    0    0  17.28 
03:28:36  12.8   0.0   2.4  84.8   0.1    1   1749    699    0    0    1  11.82 
03:28:46  11.6   0.0   1.7  86.7   0.0    1   1190    553    0    0    0  11.56 
03:28:56  16.8   0.0   2.4  80.7   0.1    1   1455    680    4    0    4  13.48 
03:29:06  14.7   0.0   1.9  83.4   0.1    2   1486    696    0    0    0  16.11 
03:29:16  22.6   0.0   3.1  74.3   0.0    3   2494    987    0    0    0  13.68 
03:29:26   4.3   0.0   0.8  94.9   0.1    2    806    391    0    0    1  12.05 
03:29:36   5.4   0.0   1.6  93.0   0.1    1   1219    665    4    0    2  11.85
```

Which is better. But a breakdown on components is missing. Or I don't know how to get them.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get an accurate reading of the whole computer's power consumption is to use [an external power meter such as this one, for example](https://www.amazon.ca/RioRand-Digital-Electricity-Monitor-Voltage/dp/B00K7VMJYM/).

Anything built-in will be flawed and ignore certain aspects like the energy loss inside the power supply and its fan, and possibly wrongly evaluate certain component consumption.

Comment: Another option is to open the case and use a voltmeter, and cross fingers not to make a short circuit :).  Just kidding.  But yes, you're right, any software based measure will not be a good measure.  At best, a software based measure has statistical value against other software measures (which turns to be good enough for some uses).

Comment: So ideally I'd have an outside meter plus an inside meter, right?

Comment: Apparently there's a middle way. Measurement while on battery. See the question update. This applies to `powertop` too, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Intel's `powertop` shows exactly that, power consumption by device.  It even has a tunnables tab where it attempts to change parameters of these devices to use less energy.

Although written by Intel (surprisingly as open-source), it has been ported to ARM based machines.

References

- [powertop (horrible) intel page](https://01.org/powertop)
- [Arch Wiki on powertop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/powertop)

Comment: I've already checked it. And found this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74942/power-consumption-monitoring-problem And have the same objection. No power consumption numbers (I have v. 2.8.).

Comment: @tomas - Hmmm... do you have `pciutils` installed? That is what reads the configuration registers on the PCI devices.  Also, powertop needs some time (a couple of minutes sometimes) to actually get consumption estimates.

Comment: Yes. Should I let `powertop` know about this explicitly? Does it care?

Comment: @tomas - for now just leave it running for some time (and cross fingers).  I have v2.8 and it works more-or-less well, but I do use it from time to time so it got some data to make the stats on.